# Is it specify to write a programme in predefined manner

Tags: c, scanf

Q1

```
int main() 
{
    char c;
    int y; 

    scanf("%c%d",&c,&y); 
    printf("%c\n%d\n",c,y); 

}
```

Answer -- If we input values then the answer will be  `z  1988 z 1988`

But in another question 
Q2

```
int main()
{
    int y; 
    char x; 
    scanf("%d",&y); 
    scanf("%c",&x); 
    printf("1 =%d\n%c\n",y,x); 
}
```

Answer -- If we input these values  `1988 1 =1988`

There are showing only integer value not character value.
My question is there are shown both the question has same pattern why one is showing  character value and other not

Comment: In the second case, count the newlines after the output. You have an extra blank line there, don't you?

Comment: Please format the question such that it becomes readable. I tried to edit, but frankly I don't capture enough to know how to do this. Also your question title makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

> Q2

```
int main()
{
    int y; 
    char x; 
    scanf("%d",&y); 
    scanf("%c",&x); 
    printf("1 =%d\n%c\n",y,x); 
}
```

The second `scanf` reads the newline character due to the <kbd>enter</kbd> key stroke.

Put a space after `scanf` like this

```
int main() 
{ 
    int y; 
    char x; 
    scanf("%d",&y); 
    scanf(" %c",&x); 
           ^----Note space
    printf("1 =%d\n%c\n",y,x); 
}
```

Comment: Im just simple entering the value if i write q2 in this manner
scanf("%d%c",&y,&x); Its showing the same result ... Why ??